# About batch updates to mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, jvm, mybatis

I want batch update data, so i use two methods.
The 1st, update in 'for' cycle, and all in one transactional.
And 2nd, joining together the 'case-when' SQL in mybatis's xml.
I think the 1st will be high-efficiency, but my test conclusion not that, for example, when i update 5000 data, these methods's efficiency is same, but the 2nd method use too many jvm memory, specifically the G1 Old Gen and the G1 Survivor Space, and it's can't recycle in time.
I don't know why is that, please give me your answer.

The project base on Springboot 2.0.6, use MySQL 5.

The 1st method, update in 'for' cycle.

```
    @Transactional
    public void testUpdate(){
        User user;
        long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 1; i < 5000; i++){
            user = new User();
            user.setId(i);
            user.setUsername(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            user.setEmail(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            user.setPassword(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            user.setPhone(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            userMapper.updateByPrimaryKey(user);
        }
        long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("testUpdateT  ************************     " + (b-a));
    }
```

The 2st method, joining together the 'case-when' SQL in mybatis's xml.

```
        public void testUpdateBatch(){
        User user;
        long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1;i<5000;i++){
            user = new User();
            user.setId(i);
            user.setUsername(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            user.setEmail(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            user.setPassword(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            user.setPhone(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5));
            list.add(user);
        }
        userMapper.updateBatch(list);
        long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("testUpdateT  ************************     " + (b-a));
    }
```

the sql

```
  <update id="updateBatch">
    update user
    <trim prefix="set" suffixOverrides=",">
      <trim prefix="username =case" suffix="end,">
        <foreach collection="list" item="i" index="index">
          when id=#{i.id} then #{i.username}
        </foreach>
      </trim>
      <trim prefix=" password =case" suffix="end,">
        <foreach collection="list" item="i" index="index">
          when id=#{i.id} then #{i.password}
        </foreach>
      </trim>
      <trim prefix="email =case" suffix="end," >
        <foreach collection="list" item="i" index="index">
          when id=#{i.id} then #{i.email}
        </foreach>
      </trim>
      <trim prefix="phone =case" suffix="end," >
        <foreach collection="list" item="i" index="index">
          when id=#{i.id} then #{i.phone}
        </foreach>
      </trim>
    </trim>
    where
    <foreach collection="list" separator="or" item="i" index="index" >
      id=#{i.id}
    </foreach>
  </update>
```

This table have 27000 items, the 1st cost 5500ms and the 2nd cost 8000-10000ms, and the most important, when the 2nd method complete, the heap memory usage gets larger, and it's can't GC in a short period of time.

Comment: Are you using `BATCH` executor in the first method? When you say that the second method `can't recycle in time`  what do you mean exactly? When do you expect the memory to be released?

Comment: I don't use batch executor.Now,I know the big object will going to Old Gen directly, so before next full GC, it can't be recycle.Thx your answer!